# Fix WP Bouncing IBM MobileFirst 6.3

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I found the plugin to fix WP bouncing in cordova : 
https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-fix-wp-bouncing

I want to implement the plugin into my MFP project.

Native Code :

```
void border_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e) {

           browser.InvokeScript("eval", "FixWPBouncing.onmanipulationcompleted()");

}
```

Javascript Code :

```
exports.onmanipulationcompleted = function () {
            exports.target = null;
};

exports.fix = function (target) {
    if (!POINTER_DOWN) { return; }
    if (!(target instanceof HTMLElement) && target.length) {
              target = target[0];
    }
target.addEventListener(POINTER_DOWN, function () { exports.target = target; }, false); };
```

plugin.xml :

```
<js-module src="www/fix-wp-bouncing.js" name="fix-wp-bouncing">
                <clobbers target="FixWPBouncing" />
</js-module>

<!-- windows phone 8 -->
<platform name="wp8">
<config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
       <feature name="FixWPBouncing">
                   <param name="wp-package" value="FixWPBouncing"/>
                   <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
</config-file>
```

How to call :

```
// call fix after deviceready.

    var wrapper = document.getElementById('an-element-that-scrolls');
    FixWPBouncing.fix(wrapper);

// I don’t have any idea where i must write this code below :
declare module FixWPBouncing {
   /** when target is a JQuery, it process the first element only. */
   export function fix(target: HTMLElement|JQuery): void;
}
```

From the code above, this is my explanation :

1. `call FixWPBouncing.fix(wrapper);` => it will call the javascript function exports.fix, The purpose of this function is adding the event listener when we touch the element.
2. The listener in the native code `void border_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)` will trigger the javascript code `exports.onmanipulationcompleted`
3. `<param name="onload" value="true" />` => The purpose of this configuration, is autoload the Native Code, so i don’t need to call cordova.exec

Because of that, i think to integrate the javascript code and the native code, i will need :

```
<js-module src="www/fix-wp-bouncing.js" name="fix-wp-bouncing">
               <clobbers target="FixWPBouncing" />
</js-module>
```

So the native code listener will always trigger the javascript code.

I feel confused to change the logic like : https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/windows-phone-8-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/

Because from that link, we call the native with cordova.exec.
Not with autoload and automatically trigger the javascript code.
Please correct me if i’m wrong.

Do you have any idea to implement : https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-fix-wp-bouncing in the MFP project ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing a Cordova plug-in in a Hybrid application, you must follow the instructions as provided in the MobileFirst Platform Developer Center tutorial.

Implementing it based on other instructions is untested/supported.

Of course, you can always choose to use a "pure" Cordova application in MobileFirst Platform Foundation **7.1**, negating the need to go through anything related to MPF and instead follow standard Cordova procedures.